# UK Permitted Paid Engagement Visa Delay, Advice?

Tags: visas, uk

I am a US citizen and applied for a permitted paid engagement visa in hopes to conduct a workshop in early November. The application was received by the UKVI in New York on September 24 and I paid for 5-day priority service. It has been 18 working days since then and all I get from the helpline is that they aim to process during these times but that they are not guaranteed.

If they prolong the delay then there wont be enough time to do the workshop. So what happens if my application contained information for a November visit but the decision is delayed past November? Is it rejected, do they give me a different date or entry or what?

Comment: Once the event date passes the premise for going to the UK no longer exists and they should and would rightfully refuse you. The expedited processing thing is many times just a sham and money grab by UK immigration. I never recommend it unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is once the event date passes, the premise for going to the UK no longer exists and they should and would rightfully refuse you.

Expedited fees should only be paid for the most straightforward cases. Applicant should note that paying priority service fees does not compel the UK visa office to adjudicate complex cases within the time period and they routinely exceed the stated period for such cases.